# Executing linux commands with PHP

Tags: php, shell, scripting

I'm trying to execute a linux command through a PHP command-line script, which is no problem using the exec command.

The problem is, the command I am executing (mysqldump) outputs an error message if something is wrong (for example user/password is incorrect). I can't seem to be able to capture this error in order to log it. It just prints this error to the screen.

How do I cause this error not to be printed to the screen, but instead to put it in a variable for use in my script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [popen](http://php.net/popen) to run the process. The example #2 on this page shows exactly what you're looking for:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Add redirection so we can get stderr. */
$handle = popen('/path/to/spooge 2>&1', 'r');
echo "'$handle'; " . gettype($handle) . "\n";
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
echo $read;
pclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: @edanb:This is a good enough solution. But I am not a fan of bash, so I recommend proc_open if you are willing to spend a little more time on handling errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
exec("mysqldump -u user -p passwod database >  outputfile.sql 2> error.log");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [redirect stderr to stdout](http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn50.html), so you can capture it. This example routes stdout to devnull (thus ignoreing it) and routes stderr to you:

```
exec('ls * 2>&1 1>/dev/null');
```

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize any user input! escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too hot in Unix (New Years Resolution...) but these functions look helpful:

- **[`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)** - returns result as a string.
- **[`passthru`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)** - It looks like you can execute this like: `passthru('command', $result);` and then use `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) command?  It's been a while since I did any PHP, but that rings a bell.

Answer (score 0):

tried using backticks?

```
$var = `command`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will route stderr messages to the same place as the normal output.

```
exec("mysql_dump blah 2>&1",$output,$return_val)
if($return_val !== 0) 
echo "there was an error"
```

2>&1 means re-route stderr messages to the same place as stdout, and thus will be loaded into the output array.