# Can PHP execute a terminal command

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Executing linux commands with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503633/executing-linux-commands-with-php)

I have a PHP file that creates an `.xfdf` file I am wondering if PHP has a way of executing a command like you would type into the terminal window? I have to run the following command when after the `.xfdf` file is created to generate the `.pdf` file

```
pdftk /var/www/pdf/TimeCard.pdf fill_form /var/www/pdf/results/Brandon_01_23_13.xfdf output /var/www/pdf/results/testNew.pdf flatten
```

The command would need to be able to accept a PHP variable so its customized for the user. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Just check the related questions on your bottom-right side of this page!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [pcntl_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php), [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).

```
$command = 'pdftk /var/www/pdf/TimeCard.pdf fill_form /var/www/pdf/results/Brandon_01_23_13.xfdf output /var/www/pdf/results/testNew.pdf flatten';
exec($command);
```

Be very careful when using these commands, they are very useful/powerful, but because of this a hacker could potentially gain access to your whole server through it (depending on permissions, but it's more than enough to compromise your site).

If you need to send user uploaded file names/text, check them to the blood (for example check if the file path is in the proper place, and not `../../../something.pdf`, check MIME types and extensions).

Comment: do you have any advice on how to safeguard against this?

Comment: I added some more info, but I would need to know what's the data that you receive from users.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use:

1. [system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)
2. [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
3. [passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

Comment: what does passthru have to do with any of this?

Comment: passthru — Execute an external program and display raw output

Comment: "This function should be used in place of exec() or system() when the output from the Unix command is binary data which needs to be passed directly back to the browser."

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact requirements, you can use `exec()`, `system()` or `shell_exec()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) functions.

But make sure the user can not inject arbitrary commands!