# php filesystem functions

Tags: php, filesystems

is there a way to make a php file execute the php filesystem functions?
or just send a ssh command via the php file ?
this is what I have so far very  basic :

```
$cmd = $_GET['cmd'];
if (isset($cmd)){

    echo $cmd;
    return $cmd;

    }
```

the idea is I can do localhost/file.php?cmd=mkdir('meow');

and it create a folder called meow.
if I do localhost/file.php?cmd=rmdir('meow') 
it removes it.
if i do chown, unlink etc etc...  you get the concept.I started writing each one alone.But  I am wondering if there is a way to make it work this way.any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want to make a directory?

Comment: PHP has lots of built-in filesystem functions. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php

Comment: Is `eval()` the function you're looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475175/can-php-execute-a-terminal-command/14475213#14475213

Answer (score 2):

OMG! Are you sure you want to do something like this? Imagine someone calling:

```
localhost/file.php?cmd=rm -rf /;
```

It's really dangerous and I strongly suggest you to avoid this practice.

Comment: This would be very fun(ny).

Comment: yes thats what i want to do. it will not be used by anyone just by me and i have a bigger idea for it :) but this is the basis so im trying to figure it out.

Comment: it's a duplicate question, you can find the answer in the question I linked before